# Why won't either toilet in my mobile home flush?

Tags: toilet

We have two bathrooms on either side of our trailer. For some reason neither of the toilets want to flush. The back fills up with water, I flush and the water sits in the bowl and doesn't drain at all. I've plunged the hell out of it. It's been snaked. I don't know what else to do. Someone HELP!!

Comment: Does the tank empty and doesn't go down the drain at all or just takes some time? Do any other drains have issues? How about the shower or bathroom sinks?

Comment: *“It’s been snaked”* with what?  If the answer is a small toilet snake then you need to move to a roto-rooter machine.  The fact both are clogged indicates the problem is further down the line.  Hopefully it’s tree-roots and debris and not a collapsed line.

Comment: How cold is it where you live? The sewage line may have froze between trailer bottom and ground. I'd add a pound of salt to each toilet, stir around to dissolve, then flush when possible. -Should clear out ice.

Answer (score 1):

Well I am leaving this as an answer because of limited information.if you live in a park contact the superintendent. If on your own property your pipes or tank can be plugged. More information is needed. And you may need to have your tank pumped. I have helped a firend that had a park and with floods one of the tanks floated several inches and broke the pipes the filled with mud and several homes had the exact problems you have more info is needed.